# gdb debug a core dump remote

Tags: debugging, gdb

A programm created a crash/core dump. I want to debug this. On my target device there is just gdbserver running. I tried various things, but couldn't manage this. 
I would appreciate, if core file could stay in device.
Binary is on device, sources on my PC, where I can run gdb.

Answer (score 1):

> I would appreciate, if core file could stay in device.

I don't believe `gdbserver` supports debugging anything other than a live process.

If that's true, you *must* transfer the `core`, binary and all shared libraries from the device to the host, and use `gdb` on the host to look inside the core.